# Web Forms for Marketers Send Email Drop List values not appearing in email

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.5

I'm using the standard "Send Email" Save Action on a form and when the email is sent the value is missing. I've manually entered list values, and used existing Sitecore items as list values but it doesn't seem to matter. I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest what the issue would be. Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore and the WFFM module?

Comment: Can you check in your mail template that the guid is correct? It has to match with the id of your field item.

Comment: I'm running Sitecore 7.5 with WFFM 2.5. And yes, the guid for the field that's inserted in the email matches that of the field item for the drop-down. One note is that when I change the field type to a radio list it works.

Comment: This might help (known issue with list fields in a.o. v2.5): https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/311218

Comment: Thanks, Gatogordo, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the [article](http://kb.sitecore.net/articles/311218) posted by Gatogordo fixed my issue.